# How do I change (old-fashioned Mac OS) File Type on some files in git working tree?

Tags: git, osx-lion

Some of my (Mac OS) files need to have a File Type of TEXT. I'm not talking about extensions, but extended attributes. That feature is lost by git.

So I need to run the SetFile command on files with a certain extension but I haven't figured out how to do it. I only need to do this in the checkout direction- nothing needs to be saved during commits.

I've looked at Ruby scripts as smudge filters but don't know how to get the file name. Is this the right approach or would a hook be better?

(I have no control over the need for File Types- it's a legacy system and I can't change the way it works.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `git hooks --help`:

```
post-checkout
   This hook is invoked when a git checkout is run after having updated
   the worktree. The hook is given three parameters: the ref of the
   previous HEAD, the ref of the new HEAD (which may or may not have
   changed), and a flag indicating whether the checkout was a branch
   checkout (changing branches, flag=1) or a file checkout (retrieving a
   file from the index, flag=0). This hook cannot affect the outcome of
   git checkout.
```

So you could have a post-checkout hook that runs over all files in the work tree that have the particular extension you care about, and invoke `SetFile` on them.  This is not perfect as it will re-do the operation on files that have not changed, and will not run at all after a `git reset --hard`, but may suffice for your needs.

A post-checkout hook that will do this for all files named `*.txt` (but no others) is pretty trivial:

```
#! /bin/sh
git ls-files -z -- '*.txt' | xargs -0 SetFile -t TEXT
```

The `-z` and `-0` make this work for hard-case pathnames (ones containing embedded spaces, for instance).

Comment: torek, many thanks for this. I pasted your code into post-checkout exactly as you submitted it, and it worked the first time!